# Routing static pages with Flask or Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

When using:

```
@route('/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='.')
```

it allows to serve the request `www.example.com/helloworld` with the static HTML file `/myapp/helloworld`.

**How to make `www.example.com/anything` be served by the static HTML file `/myapp/html/anything.html`, without having to hardcode each static filename `anything` in the Python code?**

Note: the tricky part is that the request is `/anything` (and not `/anything.html`), and the static file is `/myapp/html/anything.html` (there are 20 or more such files)

Comment: You would probably have to write some code to massage the inputs. Is it just `.html` files you want to serve?

Answer (score 0):

If it's always `.html` you could consider simply doing `filename += '.html'`.

If your needs are more complex, you could write code that examines the directory to match various extensions. For example, if you wanted to match .html files, something like this would work and would be adjustable to work with various/multiple extensions or other conditions.

```
def is_html(filename):
    return filename.lower().endswith('.html')

@route('/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    root = '.'
    all_filenames = os.listdir(root)
    html_files = filter(is_html, all_filenames)
    for fname in html_files:
        if fname.startswith(filename):
            return static_file(fname, root=root)
    else:
        return "No such file"
```

This can probably be abbreviated using fnmatch or something similar.

Although, you may want to simply consider simply having a webserver like Apache simply serve that path instead of using Flask. This would probably be a more secure option, too.